# How to predict some images by trained model on Tensorflow

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, machine-learning, prediction

I'm a super beginner. I checked the official site [Transfer learning with a pretrained ConvNet](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning). I'd like to make predictions by the site's trained model. The following code is wrong? And I'd like to know that “image” and “class name”. Hm.. How should I do?... Please give me some advice…

```
predictions = model.predict(test_batches)[1]
print(predictions)
#[-0.11642772]
```

Comment: Please add more information. What is the error you're getting? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry about that. I executed the same program of the site. After that, I'd like to make a prediction, and I wrote the above program. But I couldn't understand the getting value, and I wanted to look the image and know the class name..

Answer (score 1):

First of all Tensorflow is horrible.  Incredibly error-prone and difficult to install and use.  I would recommend using Pytorch tutorials instead.  Second, the link you posted has a Colab button.  Did you try clicking that button?  Colab makes installation easier because it’s online and not on your computer.

Also transfer learning is NOT a beginner topic.  Maybe try an easier notebook, if that works for you: https://github.com/sgrvinod/Deep-Tutorials-for-PyTorch/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. As you mentioned, I think it's difficult to handle Thensorflow...